# Android keystore system that supports API level 14 and below

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I want to store some keys in keystore in api level 14 and below. I found code to generate keystore using KeyPairGeneratorSpec and keychain , but that supported on api level 18 and above.

```
    KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(this)
      .setAlias(alias)
      .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
      .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
      .setStartDate(start.getTime())
      .setEndDate(end.getTime())
      .build();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    generator.initialize(spec);

    KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

I tried the above code but that is not supporting below api level 18.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Android Keystore System that supports API Level 14 and below. The [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SecurityFeatures) was introduced in API Level 18.

However, the [KeyChain API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/package-summary.html) (which the Android Keystore System makes use of) is available from API Level 14 and *above* (though it is now deprecated). The `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` class used in your code is part of this API ([`KeyGenParameterSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html) should be used in API Level 23 and above instead). There is no Android provided API that works below API Level 14.

Your code (without the `"AndroidKeyStore"` provider parameter) will work on API Level 14 and above.

For API Level 14 and *below*, as [another answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17366707/5115932), you can look into installing a third-party security API; such as [Spongy Castle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/).

Answer (score -1):

Per the [documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.html), you should use KeyGenParameterSpec instead. For example (for an RSA signing key):

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
kpg.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
    "mykey", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
    .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
    .build());
```